# Copy and paste Delphi for Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have the following scenario: Delphi XE7 and an Android emulator environment (Andy). I use the following command to paste text in Windows environment to operate correctly:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), 0, 0);
    keybd_event(Ord('V'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('V'), 0), 0, 0);
    keybd_event(Ord('V'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('V'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
end;
```

The formstyle option form is set to fsStayOnTop.
Now with the Android emulator running, I need to paste the text, for example, in the Google search bar in the emulator and the paste command does not work.

I noticed that if I hold the right mouse button for 2 seconds, the paste option appears (Android environment) and by clicking on it I can paste, but I need it to be automatic. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hold the right mouse button down for 2 seconds, and click on the paste button. If you are going to do this by input faking, that is what you must do.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard input is processed by the foreground window.  You are injecting keystrokes into the same low-level input queue that the keyboard itself posts user input to (BTW, you should be using [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead of `keybd_event()`).  Your simulated keystrokes go through all the same processing and routing that user-entered keystrokes go through.  Raymond Chen has a nice description on this on his website:

[When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)

When you click on your button, your app's window is in the foreground.  Thus, your <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> sequence gets received by your app, not by the Andy emulator.  And if you use a `TWinControl`-derived button, like `TButton`, it takes input focus when clicked (to avoid that, use a `TGraphicControl`-derived button instead, like `TSpeedButton`).  Since an edit control is not focused, the <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> appears to do nothing because there is nothing to paste into when the keystokes are processed.

You need to use [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) (and maybe also [`SetFocus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312.aspx)) to bring Andy's window back to the foreground and give it input focus **before** you then send your keystrokes.

Even then, there is no 100% guarantee that *some other* app can't steal focus between the time you issue the keystrokes and time they come out of the input queue.

Comment: Ctrl+V is meaningless in Android. The asker wants the paste to happen in the android app.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Granted, Android itself does not recognize Ctrl-V, but the question is about an Android emulator running on Windows, so who is to say the emulator itself does not handle Ctrl-V and copy text from the Windows clipboard to Android's clipboard and paste it into the current Android UI control?  I tried to use Andy once before and had nothing but problems with it (it would never start correctly), so I don't know what kind of cross-interaction functionality actually works in the emulator level at the platform boundary.

Comment: I am unable to copy the contents of the Windows clipboard to the Android environment. I entered the GooglePlay, downloaded an application and would like to perform the filling of fields in this application via Delphi. I tried to copy and paste, then simulate the grip of each key (keybd_event (65,0,0,0);) but does not work.

Comment: @Luana: If you can't copy/paste using the real keyboard, you won't be able to copy/paste using simulated keystrokes. If Andy supports Ctrl-V then you are not simulating it correctly (hence my answer above). If Andy links the two clipboards together internally, you may have to simulate mouse long presses within Android, like David suggested, instead of simulating Ctrl-V on the keyboard. So first you need to figure out how Andy supports copy/paste between Windows and Android in the first place, and then you can figure you how to simulate it in code. Without involving code, what *DOES* work?